# Is it okay to save to the browser localstorage 25 times per second?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, local-storage

I think the title is pretty much descriptive. I'm working on a idle game project using Ember.js and for now I'm saving to the localstorage 25 times per second instead of saving every 10 or 20 seconds. It's a really small amount of data and I'm not experiencing any performance issue (at least in my machine), but I'd like to know if this is bad and if so, how bad it is. Thanks :)

Comment: You could run some load testing, see where it fails and how close you are to it. -see how many times you can save per second with the amount of data you are saving before failure, -see how much data you can save 25 times per second before failure

Comment: You could try multiple browsers, and create virtual machines via [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (and http://modern.ie/ for getting Windows test environments) with different hardware configurations in order to get a better idea of its performance on different kinds of systems.

Comment: *Why* save at 25fps, even if there is no "performance" issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things :

**1 )** Each browser supports different intervals of `getting` or `setting` `localstorage` `values`

If you performs too many times within a period the browser may hang and become unresponsive!

For best performance you should save to a local variable then periodically save it to `localstorage`.

Here are the list of browser's and their time taken to first read or write:

- On Chrome, the first read takes ~1ms and subsequent reads take 0ms.
- On Firefox, the first read takes ~0.5ms and subsequent reads take ~0.1ms.
- On Internet Explorer 9, all reads take 0ms. I’m not sure how Internet Explorer is loading this data, but it doesn't appear to be the same as with other browsers.
- On Opera, first read takes ~1ms and subsequent reads take 0ms.
- For Safari on iOS 6, the very first read takes up to 24ms and subsequent reads take 0ms.

**2 )** It also depends on the size of values that you are getting/setting.

**Remember** :

**-**`localstorage` has a limited capacity per domain and browser.

**-** And avoid to use `localstorage` while your page loads.

*As my opinion* : Give maximum time to `localstorage` if you don't want to crssh your game while user's are playing.

And calculate that maximum amount of data is used while user play the game and set time to write `localstorage`.

Comment: I was aware of the size limitation, but is really good to have this data at the specific time in each browser. I think having it to save every 10 or 20 seconds is a better idea. Thanks